# hidden field in php

Tags: php, html

For hidden fields, can i use a field of the type

```
<input type="hidden" name="field_name" value="<?php print $var; ?>"/>
```

and retrieve it after the GET / POST method as `$_GET['field_name'] / $_POST['field_name'] ?`

are there any other ways of using hidden fields in php?

Comment: A general note; make sure you are accessing the elements by `name` and not `id` in the postback!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You absolutely can, I use this approach a lot w/ both JavaScript and PHP.

Field definition:

```
<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="<?php echo $var;?>" />
```

Access w/ PHP:

```
$_GET['foo'] or $_POST['foo']
```

Also: Don't forget to sanitize your inputs if they are going into a database.  Feel free to use my routine: https://github.com/niczak/PHP-Sanitize-Post/blob/master/sanitize.php

Cheers!

Comment: I am trying to print this variable, $html = '<input type="hidden" name="field_name" value="<?php print $var; ?>"/>'; the value is picked up as string along with php tags... how can i fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can access it through `GET` and `POST` (trying this simple task would have made you aware of that).

Yes, there are other ways, one of the other "preferred" ways is using [sessions](http://www.php.net/session). When you would want to use hidden over session is kind of touchy, but any GET / POST data is easily manipulated by the end user. A session is a bit more secure given it is saved to a file on the server and it is much harder for the end user to manipulate without access through the program.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use a field of the type ... and retrieve it after the GET / POST method ...

Yes (haven't you tried?)

> Are there any other ways of using hidden fields in PHP?

You mean other ways of retrieving the value? No.
Of course you can use hidden fields for what ever you want.

---

Btw. `input` fiels have no end tag. So write either just `<input ...>` or as self-closing tag `<input .../>`.