# add the value of javascript in the hidden field

Tags: php, javascript, field, hidden

I have this javascript line

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write(top.location);</script>
```

and this code

```
<form action="rating.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="url" value="xxxx" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>

<?

echo $_POST["url"];

?>
```

Please, How i can add the value of javascript (xxx) in the hidden field?

Also does it possible to let `<input type="submit" />`have automatic submit ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "How can i add the value of javascript in the hidden field?" What do you mean with automatic submit?

Comment: Hidden field, save value of javascript in hidden field and postback to php, this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949847/hidden-field-in-php

Comment: "automatic submit" submit the inputs without click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this, in order to feed the hidden field?

```
<input type="hidden" name="url" value="<? echo $_POST["url"]; ?>" />
```

Regarding submit, you can use javascript to handle the submit event:

If you add the attribute `name="FORMNAME"` inside the `<form ... >` tag, you can use:

```
document.FORMNAME.submit();
```

for submitting the form, without using the submit button.

In order to **feed a hidden field through javascript**, use:

```
document.FORMNAME.url.value = top.location;
```

Comment: as already asked from BenniKa, what do you mean with automatic submit?

Comment: The value of url field = <script type="text/javascript">document.write(top.location);</script>

Comment: WHAT would you like to ACHIEVE with "automatic submit"?

Comment: "automatic submit" submit the inputs without click

Comment: forget about automatic submit"..just want to to replace xxx with the javascript value

Comment: @masterio I've updated my answer, regarding updating a hidden field with a javascript value.