# Check if form has been submitted to itself once do one thing if back again do another?

Tags: php, forms, submit, crud

I have a form that submits to itself.  When I want to edit something I take the data and place it in place of empty fields.  I am trying to make a check to see if the the form has already been submitted once so that it knows that if it has come back again and put data in the blank fields on the next submit it runs an update query.

I thought what I would do is make a variable after the query is run the first time called `$submitted` and set that to `true`  then when the form goes back to itself and see that `true` it can set another variable to `$submitted_twice` which will then let me run the edit query.

This approach doesn't seem to be working and I can not figure out why.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Post your code please, and we can help you work the logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That wouldn't work because that variable is not persistent. Some alternatives to store this var across requests could be:

1. Use the $_SESSION global var to store the number of times your form has been submitted:

   (Here I'm assuming your form uses POST as requesting method, and your submit button id is "submit")

   ```
   if( $SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && !empty( $_POST['submit'] ) ){

         //
         //deal with your form action here
         //

         //Here's the bit where you store/update your counter
         if( !isset( $_SESSION['submitted'] ){
             $_SESSION['submitted'] = 1;
         else {
             $_SESSION['submitted']++;
         }

         //Echo your counter
         echo "This form has been submitted " . $_SESSION['submitted'] . " time(s)";

   }
   ```
2. Use a hidden field in the form to store your counter. Check this answer [hidden field in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949847/hidden-field-in-php)

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Do you know why it doesn't persist but a hidden field does?  It seems to me like they are basically the same thing but maybe I am missing something?

Comment: The main difference is that using the hidden field you are actually storing and retrieving your value on every request. 

This is you are saving your counter in the hidden field's value, which later on is going to be submitted to the server on every request and, therefore, the latter can make use of it.